# How should `hg rebase` be used?

Tags: mercurial

I have two branches `default` and `bug`, I want to rebase `bug` branch with last commit from `default` branch. I've tried:

```
hg phase --draft --force -r bug
hg rebase -d default
```

**Result:** I have `default` branch with my commits from `bug` branch. Which is not exactly what I want, so now I have two issues:

1. How can I cancel rebase and checkout my `default` branch equal to repository?
2. How should I work with `hg rebase` that it change the `bug` branch, not `default`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When you rebased incorrectly, Mercurial normally saves a backup in `.hg\strip-backup`.  Restore that backup with `hg pull <path_to_backup>`.  Then, `hg strip -r <incorrect_rebased_rev>`.  That should put you back where you started.
2. `hg rebase -r default -d bug` will move the latest default changeset to the tip of bug.